RPC request error when requesting devnet airdrop and during anchor deploy
I am trying to deploy my first anchor program and I got it to successfully build. However when I try to deploy it, it returns the error,

Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: HTTP status
server error (503 Service Unavailable) for url
(https://api.devnet.solana.com/) There was a problem deploying: Output
{ status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

I also tried getting devnet tokens, but it returns a similar error,

Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: HTTP status
server error (503 Service Unavailable) for url
(https://api.devnet.solana.com/)

I checked and the devnet should be up and I do have a wallet under .config/solana/id.json.

Solana Devnet is currently down. This seems to be happening quite often now.
It might be worth using localnet where possible.
